# Why does the Race use EMP weapons on a society that recently just perfected the vacuum tube?

Tags: harry-turtledove, worldwar-series

In the first book of the Worldwar series, the Race, upon hearing that the Tosevites have invented the radio, but have not achieved space flight, decide that in order to make their invasion less of a hassle would be to use their nuclear arsenal to sabotage global communication on Tosev III. All they succeeded in doing was announcing their presence to the natives and partially irradiated a few industrial centers.

Wouldn't the expeditionary force sent to Tosev III be able to deduce that while the Tosevites have invented the radio, but not space flight, that they have not created the silicon chip yet, therefore rendering the EMP strike useless?

Comment: When was the vacuum tube "perfected" in our timeline? Has it been perfected?